# Html parsing and grabbing URL's by using DOMdocument

Tags: php, web-scraping, domdocument

Trying to grab URLs. But my `foreach` loop just returns the URL from the first two `<div>` elements. It doesn't go any further.

**Function:**

```
function getSiteContent($url)
{
    $html = cache()->rememberForever($url, function () use ($url) {
        return file_get_contents($url);
    });

    $parser = new \DOMDocument();
    $parser->loadHTML($html);
    return $parser;

}
```

**Code:**

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$url = 'http://www.sumitomo-rd-mansion.jp/kansai/';
$parser = getSiteContent($url);

$allDivs = $parser->getElementsByTagName('div');
foreach ($allDivs as $div) {
   if ($div->getAttribute('id') == 'areaWrap') {
      $innerDivs = $div->getElementsByTagName('div');
      foreach ($innerDivs as $innerDiv) {
         if ($innerDiv->getAttribute('class') == 'areaBox clearfix') {
             $links = $innerDiv->getElementsByTagName('a');
             if ($links->length > 0) {
                 $a = $links->item(0);
                 $linkRef = $a->getAttribute('href');
                 $link [] = $linkRef;
             }
         }
      }
   }
}

var_dump($link);
```

**Result:**

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(65) "http://www.sumitomo-rd-mansion.jp/kansai/higashi_umeda/index.html"
  [1]=>
  string(60) "http://www.sumitomo-rd-mansion.jp/kansai/osaka745/index.html"
}
```

with this code I just getting first and second div `areaBox`. And stopping there. Is my foreach loop wrong? Or is website has some obsticle which is
stopping the scrape? Thank you for helping me out.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache? Maybe you have an old version of the site in your cache.

Comment: @Remul yep, actually I tried no effects... still getting just two no further more...

Comment: Did you try with`simple_html_dom` cause it can parse them all?

Comment: no I didn't, I thought DOMdocument better then that. In the end, I don't know how to use it as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the desired result using `simple_html_dom`. I used this library because it supports css selector. Try the below script.

```
<?php
include("simple_html_dom.php");

$weblink = "http://www.sumitomo-rd-mansion.jp/kansai/";
function fetch_sumitomo_links($weblink)
{
    $htmldoc   = file_get_html($weblink);
    foreach ($htmldoc->find(".name a") as $a) {
        $links[]          = $a->href . '<br>';
    }
    return $links;
}
$items = fetch_sumitomo_links($weblink);
foreach($items as $itemlinks){
    echo $itemlinks;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know there is already an accepted answer, but I would not recommend using this "simple_html_dom" library, which is more than 10 years old and undeveloped for a very long time. I suggest you stick with DomDocument, and you can use XPath queries to avoid all the loops that you do:

```
<?php
$xpath = new \DOMXPath($parser);
$nodes = $xpath->query("//div[@id='areaWrap']//div[contains(@class, 'areaBox')]//a[1]");
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $links[] = $node->getAttribute("href");
}
```

The problem you're having with this page is invalid data in the HTML. If you get rid of `libxml_use_internal_errors(true);` you will see warnings related to invalid characters. In your `getSiteContent` function you can convert the text before loading it into DomDocument:

```
$html = mb_convert_encoding($html, "SJIS", "UTF-8");
```

This gives the expected output:

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  string(65) "http://www.sumitomo-rd-mansion.jp/kansai/higashi_umeda/index.html"
  [1]=>
  string(60) "http://www.sumitomo-rd-mansion.jp/kansai/osaka745/index.html"
  [2]=>
  string(60) "http://www.sumitomo-rd-mansion.jp/kansai/kyobashi/index.html"
  [3]=>
  string(59) "http://www.sumitomo-rd-mansion.jp/kansai/tsurumi/index.html"
  [4]=>
  string(62) "http://www.sumitomo-rd-mansion.jp/kansai/kitatanabe/index.html"
  [5]=>
  string(47) "http://sumai.tokyu-land.co.jp/branz/umedanorth/"
  [6]=>
  string(63) "http://www.sumitomo-rd-mansion.jp/kansai/momoyamadai/index.html"
}
```

Comment: Thank you, mate. this will really helpful.